# How to show an indicator while data is being fetched from databased

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, sqflite

I'm trying to open the database at the app start up. When I try to read data from database it takes about 1 second or more and since the read method is `Future`, the app loads the main widget tree before the database being initialized and since the fetch method haven't done loading yet it returns NULL. Is there any other way to load the database at the app start up? Here's my code :

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MyApp(),
));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.grey);


List<int> settings = [];

getSettings() async {

  try {
    List<SettingsDB> settingsGetter = await getData('settings', 'SettingsDB');
    SettingsDB settingsDBInstance = settingsGetter[0];
    print(settingsGetter);
    settings.add(settingsDBInstance.darkThemeEnabled);
    settings.add(settingsDBInstance.freeExamsProgress);
    settings.add(settingsDBInstance.mainExamsProgress);
    settings.add(settingsDBInstance.signsExamsProgress);
    settings.add(settingsDBInstance.mixedExamsProgress);
  }catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
getSettings();

return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'title',
  home: MainPage(settings: settings,),
);
}
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

final List<int> settings;

const MainPage({Key key, this.settings}) : super(key: key);

@override
_MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {



return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffE0E0E0),
  body:

  SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[

          SizedBox(height: 36.0,),

          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Text(widget.settings[0].toString()),
          ),

          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Text(widget.settings[1].toString()),
          ),

          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Text(widget.settings[2].toString()),
          ),

          Container
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Text(widget.settings[3].toString()),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't show the user anything meaningful before you load this data, you might just as well do it before calling `runApp` by making your main method async.

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final data = await getData(); // whatever is needed to load your data
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Well actually I can show them. For instance in this example I can show the Containers but I need to wait for database to load and after that show the Numbers in Text.

Comment: Well as I said the Future will return the data when its done working but I want it to happen before app initialization. before splash screen finish.

Comment: are you sure that the splash screen disappears before `runApp` is. called? if you properly `await` your data, as I have shown i thought that it should do just that.. what's your result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FutureBuilder widget like below:

```
                       FutureBuilder(
                          future: widget._bloc.getAllPartners(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<List<UserPartner>> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Flexible(
                                child: _getSortByPartnerDropDown(snapshot.data),
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Flexible(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                      IntimassyColor.primaryTextWhiteHint),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
```